# Running Ubuntu 14.04 from USB, can I Install Ubuntu on my HD without losing my persistent Live-USB data?

Tags: ubuntu, live-usb

I've been running Ubuntu from USB for a few months and now I want to install it but without losing any of the data that I’m working on (data on the USB). Is this possible?

Comment: And where is the data? On your harddrive?

Comment: The data is on the USB and I want to make sure that the data is "sent" to the HD once I install Ubuntu.

Comment: The installation is not going to change the USB contents. After installation you can probably insert the USB and copy the data. If that wouldn't work for some reason you can boot once more from USB and copy the data to the HD.

Comment: Yes but since I've been using live-USB I downloaded packages, installed lots of software, etc. I didn't want to download tricky package dependencies and stuff all over again... But yeah I guess I have no choice, thank you.

Comment: You can probably copy over the `.deb` files from `/var/cache/apt/archives/` to the new system and install them with dpkg. No need to download (at least) those again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data now is on the USB stick, then that data will not be touched by installing Ubuntu on you harddrive.

After booting from harddrive you probably just insert the USB stick and pull the data from the stick into your new account on the harddrive.

If for some reason that would not be possible, then there is an alternative that certainly will work: boot one last time from USB, mount the newly formatted Linux partition that is on the harddrive and copy your data over from the USB stick the harddrive that way.